# c++ memcpy from a char array to an integer

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a `memcpy()` from a `charArray` to an integer variable. Copying is done but while trying to print the copied value, some garbage is getting printed. Follow my code.

Is there any issue with padding?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *tempChar;
    string inputString;
    int tempInt = 3;

    cout << "enter an integer number" << endl;
    cin >> inputString;
    tempChar = new char[strlen(inputString.c_str())];   
    strcpy(tempChar, inputString.c_str());  
    memcpy(&tempInt, tempChar, sizeof(int));
    cout << endl;
    cout << "tempChar:" << tempChar << endl;
    cout << "tempInt:" << tempInt << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you tell "garbage" from "non-garbage"? What is wrong with what you get printed? What did you expect to see in the printed value?

Comment: Do you really think that the in-memory representation of an int is something like `133742`? o.O

Answer (score 3):

Yes: you mess up the memory.

Use: `stoi()` to convert a std::string to an integer:

```
int tempInt(stoi(inputString));
```

Complete example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

   std::string tmpString;
   std::cin >> tmpString;

   int const tmpInt(stoi(tmpString));

   std::cout << tmpInt << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `atoi`. If you have to use a C library function, use `strtol`, not `atoi`. But in C++ you have better alternatives.

Comment: You are right - was just looking to do it in the C++ way. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I want the simillar behaviour using memcpy. What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: You just can't: when you input digits they will internally stored as a sequence of chars.  An integer has a completely differnt internal representation.  The `stoi()` function converts the one representation into the other.

Comment: @Prabha Satya: `memcpy` is your mistake. You can't just "want" some arbitrary behavior from `memcpy`. What you can do is read the specification of `memcpy` and realize that it does not and will not do what you need. So, forget about `memcpy`.